# Concat two columns in Where Clause in PSQL v11

Tags: pervasive

```
SELECT CONCAT(rtrim(Xyz.FirstName), rtrim(Xyz.LastName)) as person from Xyz
WHERE Person = ('JohnSmith')
```

> The above works but my input parameter would have a space in it for
>   example "John Smith". I tried adding

```
 WHERE Person = ltrim('John Smith')
```

but that did not work either.

Comment: Would you not need space in the name in the select part?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using Pervasive PSQL v11. Not sure what exact database engine

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(rtrim(Xyz.FirstName), rtrim(Xyz.LastName)) as person from Xyz
WHERE Person = ('Jon Smith')
```

won't return any records because of the space and you are `rtrim`ing the fields.
You could use something like:

```
SELECT CONCAT(rtrim(Xyz.FirstName), concat(' ', rtrim(Xyz.LastName))) as person from Xyz
WHERE Person = ('Jon Smith')
```

Notice the extra `concat` and the space (' ') in the `Select` portion.

Answer (score -1):

Just like this:

```
select * from person where trim(last_name)||trim(first_name)= replace('John  Smith', ' ', '')
```

Comment: Pervasive SQL does not support the || operators.  The statement above will generate a syntax error.